# Compare VARTYPE and typeid().name / typename in function templates

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I have the following function template:

```C++
template <typename TypeName>
TypeName AssignDefaultIfNull(VARIANT Variant, TypeName & Value) {

    if ((Variant.vt != VT_NULL) || (Variant.vt != VT_EMPTY))
    {
        CComVariant CV = Variant;

        if (CV.vt != TypeName) {} // << HERE I WANT TO COMPARE THOSE TWO, BUT THEY'RE DIFFERENT THINGS. >>
    }
    else
    {
        // Default Value
    }

    return Value;
}
```

Sometimes, I use above function template like:

```
LONG LongValue = AssignDefaultIfNull<LONG>(rcNormalPositionBottom, lpwndpl.rcNormalPosition.bottom);
```

I want above to compare `VARIANT`'s `VARTYPE (vt)` with the given typename `TypeName` and if matches, then perform some operations with them.

I tried with `!=` operator, but it cannot compare because `VARTYPE` is `unsigned short` and `TypeName` is a `typename`.

I also tried like this:

```C++
if (CV.vt != (VARTYPE)typeid(TypeName).name()) {}
```

But compiler gives a warning:

> C4302: 'type cast': truncation from 'const char*' to 'VARTYPE'

Isn't there any possible way to compare those two types correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what type `Variant` refers to in your code.  If you are using [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) you can do `if (std::holds_alternative<TypeName>(CV)) { ... }`

Comment: @HenriMenke `Variant` is assigned from VBScript for compatibility, and mostly it gets assigned with either string or integer.

Comment: Okay, but what *type* is it?  Which header defines `VARIANT` and `CComVariant`?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean. What do you mean by *type* here? No any of this project's header files specially defines them, they're just defined in stock C++ libraries I think. `CComVariant` is in `OleAut.h` maybe.

Comment: No, `VARIANT` and `CComVariant` are clearly non-standard.  And since they are not part of the core language (i.e. they are not built-in types like `int`) they *have to be* defined in a header file.

Comment: Can you show me a simple example about how to define this?

Comment: Is it maybe this one? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa519089.aspx

Comment: @HenriMenke You're right! It is the `VARIANT` I use. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomvariant-class) is the `CComVariant` class.

Comment: I don't have Visual C++, but you could try `if (CV.vt != CComVariant(TypeName{}).vt) { ... }` (needs C++11 for uniform initialisation syntax).  This creates a temporary `CComVariant` which wraps a default-initialized value of `TypeName` and retrieves the `.vt` member.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks! I will try it.

Comment: Before C++11 this might work: `if (CV.vt != CComVariant((TypeName())).vt) { ... }`

Comment: @HenriMenke what does `CComVariant(TypeName{}).vt` actually do? When I used it with above function, It gave me `3 (VT_I4)` and `8 (VT_BSTR)` for `CV.vt`. Is it reliable? What did you mean by default-initialized value? Shouldn't it return `19 (VT_UI4)` because this time I used `LONG` as `typename`? Looks like `int` is very similar with `long`.

Comment: The `CComVariant` is simply a C++ wrapper for `VARIANT`.  The `VARIANT` type is a so-called [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), i.e. it can represent different types but remembers which one was actually stored using a tag (unlike regular union), which is the `.vt` member.  The `.vt` member is an enum which assign numbers to types and apparently a signed integer maps to 3 and a `BSTR` maps to 8 (whatever type that is).  A quick search brought up this resource: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237865.aspx

Comment: Is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221170(v=vs.85).aspx) resource also describes about it?

Comment: Then why it returns `19` when I use above function with `UINT`? Isn't `UINT` smaller than `long`? `UINT` even cannot be negative.

Comment: The resource you linked looks very similar.  I don't know my way around MSDN docs, so I don't know which applies to you.  So you say that `CComVariant(long{}).vt` returns 19 which corresponds to `VT_UINT` rather than `VT_I8`?

Comment: Yes, it returns `19` **when I use above function with `UINT`, not `long`**. I think it should return `23 (VT_UINT)`. And it also returns `3` when I use above function with `LONG`, but I think it should return `19 (VT_UI4)`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you please show me an example with how to do exactly same with a `std::variant` rather than facing such difficulties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement a similar concept using `std::variant` you can define a visitor which returns a specified default value if the requested type is not stored in the variant.  Using an instantiator function one can get around explicitly specifying template argument and let template argument deduction do the heavy lifting.

Needs C++17.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>

// Leave blank incomplete to prevent uninitialized variant from
// compiling.

// struct blank;
struct blank {};

using Variant = std::variant<blank,
                             unsigned int,
                             int,
                             unsigned long,
                             long
                             /* ... */
                             >;


template < typename R >
class DefaultVisitor
{
  R m_r;
public:
  DefaultVisitor(R const& r) : m_r(r) {}

  R operator() (R const& r) { return r; }

  template < typename T >
  R operator() (T const&) { return m_r; }
};


template < typename R >
DefaultVisitor<R> make_default_visitor(R const& r)
{
  return DefaultVisitor<R>(r);
}


int main()
{
  Variant v(long{0});

  Variant w;

  std::cout << std::visit(make_default_visitor(long{12}), v) << '\n'; // 0
  std::cout << std::visit(make_default_visitor(int{17}), v)  << '\n'; // 17
}
```

Alternatively you could use Boost.Variant which is available before C++17.  This should compile from C++11 onward.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

using Variant = boost::variant<boost::blank,
                               unsigned int,
                               int,
                               unsigned long,
                               long
                               /* ... */
                               >;


template < typename R >
class DefaultVisitor :  boost::static_visitor<R>
{
  R m_r;
public:
  using result_type = R ; // need this to compile in C++11

  DefaultVisitor(R const& r) : m_r(r) {}

  R operator() (R const& r) const { return r; }

  template < typename T >
  R operator() (T const&) const { return m_r; }
};


template < typename R >
DefaultVisitor<R> make_default_visitor(R const& r)
{
  return DefaultVisitor<R>(r);
}


int main()
{
  Variant v(long{0});

  Variant w;

  std::cout << boost::apply_visitor(make_default_visitor(long{12}), v) << '\n'; // 0
  std::cout << boost::apply_visitor(make_default_visitor(int{17}), v) << '\n'; // 17
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried it yet, I will try and ask a new question if something goes wrong. :-)